# Access contents of a fragment if its path is available to rendering container

Tags: fragment, aem, sightly

I have a content fragment which hold the reference to a file under assets, on the page the fragment is rendered on a component

Example:

> Content Fragment : /content/dam/fragment_name
>
> File path under above fragment :
>   /content/dam/we-retail/en/activities/running/Image_name.jpg

Now I need to get the contents of the fragment to the component html, so that I can have full control of fragment elements programatically.

It should be achieved only through Sightly without using java sling model.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is asking other people to write code for you. This is not something that StackOverflow is meant to do for you. Please  read the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the Help Center to find out how to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: What have you tried on your end?